# Information about whether the file has been saved

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to know if there is any way to obtain information about whether the file is being edited or has been saved while it is edited online

Comment: it is generally considered a good thing to have some example code where you are trying to do what you want and asking why that isn't working. But as a general rule yes, if you use google apps script - look here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file and check the getLastUpdated  method. You can't see if someone has it open currently or is 'editing' but you can see if they updated really recently. There are also methods to lock files if you want to do things with it. Try to solve your problem and make another question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push) once set up google will inform you have changes to a file.  I dont think it will tell you that its being edited live but you will be notified if there have been changes made.